# Inputting data into a double using loop

Tags: matlab, loops, double

I have a small problem inputting data into a double using a loop. As the loop starts, the double (called **M**) is empty. I want to input data from another double (called **C**, **C** has only 1 column) into **M** one column at a time. I know there will be 12 column in **M** I don't know how many rows I'll have. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have 123 rows in **C**. I've tried something like this:

```
 M=double.empty;     
 for b=1:12
     <loop to do some computation to create C>
         for a=1:size(C,1)         
             M(1+end,b)=C(a,1)
         end
     end
 end
```

The problem here is that for the loop of b when b = 1, everything is fine. However, when b=2, data will start at **M(123+1,2)**. Thus, **M(1:123,2)=0's**. Could anyone tell me how I can input data into M in a way that the entry will always start with the first row (i.e., so that no zeros filling the space)? I'm guessing the issue is with `1+end` but I don't know how to solve it.

Edit: complete code:

```
 for b=1:length(conds_BOLD)
    for c=1:length(subj_CTL)

        PPI_comp_CTL_file=spm_select('FPList',fullfile(maindir,'PPI_component',config,roi_list{a},type,roi_format),...
            sprintf('^%s_%s_%s.*\\.mat$',subj_CTL{c},roi_list{a},conds_PPI{b}));
        PPI_comp_CTL_data=load(PPI_comp_CTL_file);

        for d=1:size(PPI_comp_CTL_data.est,1)
            M_PPI_CTL(1+end,b)=PPI_comp_CTL_data.est(d,1);
        end
     end
 end
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here? Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, the following trivial modification will make your code work.

```
M=double.empty;     
for b=1:12
    <some computation to create C>
     for a=1:size(C,1)         
         M(a,b)=C(a,1) %modified here
     end
end
```

When you do `1+end`, the `end` keyword will determine the index according to the size of the `M` matrix at that instant. Thus, in the first iteration, `end=0`, then when `b=2`, `end=size(M,1)`.

A faster way:

```
M=double.empty;     
for b=1:12
    <some computation to create C>
     M(:,b)=C;
end
```

If you could elaborate on how you compute `C`, it can be made faster. Also, instead of allocating `M` as an empty matrix, do the following:

```
M=zeros(size(C,1),12);
```

You would see considerable difference in speed when size of `C` increases.

**Updated code after OP edited the question:**

```
for b=1:12
    count=0;
    for c=1:N
       <<code which generates a new C every time>>
       M(count+1:count+size(C,1),b)=C;
       count=count+size(C,1);
    end
end
```

I hope the above snippet works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the amswer, Parag. Actually I wasn't clear with my question (my aplogies). The line <some computation to create C> actually is another loop. This way, for each loop of b, I will have multiple iterations which creates multiple C's. I want each interation of C to add to the same column M. If I do `M(a,b)=C(a,1)`, it will just write over the previous iteration of C. That's why I thought to use `end` in the first place.